# using ClassName::kEnumElement vs InstantiatedClassObject.kEnumElement?

Tags: c++, class, enums

I'm trying to do my best to write organized code using classes and would appreciate some guidance.  I want to use my enum values from within my class as a function input to improve readability.

```
//Menu.hpp
class Menu
{
private:
    int m_cursorPosition;

public:
    enum Direction {
        kUp,
        kDown
    };

    Menu();
    void moveCursor(int direction);
};
```

What, if any, are the pros/cons of using the following two methods to access the enum's values?  Is there a better way?

```
//main.cpp
#include "Menu.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Menu theMainMenu;
    theMainMenu.moveCursor(Menu::kUp);  //method 1
    theMainMenu.moveCursor(theMainMenu.kDown);  //method 2

    return 0;
}
```

I have also considered using separate functions [moveUp(), moveDown()] for each direction so I could make the enum private, but this seems like it would get cumbersome quickly if I had more than two directions.  Is there a reason I would want/need the enum to be private?

Comment: A better way is to used [scoped enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) if you use C++11

Comment: @Mine I am using C++11. Can you elaborate a little? I also use the enum values in my member functions.

Comment: You can check the link provided in my comment, or Google "scoped enum" (or "enum class") for detailed usage.